# Docker Swarm connects with worker nodes but containers in nodes can't resolve host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a long running docker swarm manager node and a worker node on two separate AWS EC2 instances (all of them connected with overlay network called `proxy`). Now, we are adding a GCP node as well during which I ran into these issues.

- Worker nodes can join and jobs are being succesffuly orchestrated by docker swarm.

However,

- Containers running on other hosts are not able to find services that are available on different host! I get could not resolve host `service_name`.
- I now also found out that If I run `docker swarm ca --rotate` on the manager node host, it remains stuck and can't get rotated certificates for any node other than for itself and othe first node. (We didn't add any new nodes in last 4 months or so).

I have checked firewall rules, etc. and everything is fine.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Port 2377/tcp is used by worker & manager nodes to connect to managers. Clearly this is allowed.

7946/tcp & udp is used as a gossip network for nodes to share docker service dns entries. Looks like this is being blocked.

4789/udp is the actual overlay traffic (when overlay encryption is not enabled). If dns succeeded, but services failed to connect then this would be implicated.